# Trying to load trivial-shell by ASDF on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, common-lisp, asdf

I'm trying to load [trivial-shell](http://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-shell/) on Mac OS X.

When I execute the following command:

```
(asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op :trivial-shell)
```

I get the following error:

```
decoding error on stream
#<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /Users/paul/lispsystems/trivial-shell.asd" 
     {129D4569}>
(:EXTERNAL-FORMAT :UTF-8):
  the octet sequence (180) cannot be decoded.
   [Condition of type SB-INT:STREAM-DECODING-ERROR]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: FWIW, you can use the much easier `(asdf:load-system :trivial-shell)` now.

Answer (score 1):

Code 180 corresponds to ACUTE_ACCENT. I don't see anything like that in trivial-shell.asd on my system, and the project loads fine in SBCL. The md5 sum of the .asd file is `934952bf4854126a1d6fca2d33baffa2`. Is yours different?

Answer (score 0):

I loaded this package with quicklisp (http://www.quicklisp.org/) on ccl; not sure quicklisp will load it using sbcl, but it might be worth a shot.